# How to run selenium-side-runner in docker?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-ide

I need to run selenium-side-runner in docker.I wrote in the dockerfile to install Google Chrome and googledrive. But when the code is executed, the error is as follows：

```
 WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
 (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
 at Object.throwDecodedError (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:550:15)
 at parseHttpResponse (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:560:13)
 at Executor.execute (../../usr/lib/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:486:26)
```

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS 
chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN npm install -g selenium-side-runner

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

this is my code:

```
for ind, file in enumerate(test_file_list):
    file_path = os.path.join(self.save_path, file)
    start_time = timezone.now()
    result = subprocess.run(
        ['selenium-side-runner', '-c', "goog:chromeOptions.args=[--headless,--nogpu] 
         browserName=chrome",file_path])
    end_time = timezone.now()
    result_code = result.returncode
```

Comment: I did some POC repo here: https://github.com/sbhusal123/sel-ide-ci

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A hack

Instead of installing a browser by hand, I would recommend using already available images like https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium.

## A solution (recommended)

From an architectural point of view, each Docker container should have only one purpose. In your case, the container is responsible for running a browser and tests. That's why I propose to split the solution into two containers:

- the first container with `selenium-side-runner` and `.side` files that will run tests
- the second container runs a browser

Based on [the docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/#running-on-selenium-grid), `selenium-side-runner` can work with a Selenium Grid.

So, the solution will look like

1. Prepare `Dockerfile` that installs `selenium-side-runner`, adds `.side` files, and configures an `ENTRYPOINT`. Here you can also set a default URL to Selenium Grid like `selenium-side-runner -w 10 --server http://selenium-browsers:4444/wd/hub` where `selenium-browsers` will be a name of the container with a browser or Selenium Grid.
2. Build your custom Docker image
3. Create Docker network with `docker network create selenium-tests`
4. Run a browser or Selenium Grid

   - Option 1: a browser. `docker run -id --shm-size=2g --network selenium-tests --name selenium-browsers selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-2020040` based on [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images)
   - Option 2: Selenium Grid. [SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) provides instructions how to do this. Also, you may look at [Zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/) or [Selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/) that provide additional features as video recordings, test execution preview, etc.
5. Run your container with `docker run -it --network selenium-tests --name my-tests <your custom image>`

As both containers are in the same custom network `selenium-tests`, both containers can communicate through the container names. So, `my-tests` container can send the requests to `selenium-browsers` container (see #1 and `--server` option).

If needed, you can create [docker-compose.yaml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) file later to simplify the usage of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved the problem successfully

Comment: @McCray how did you make to access your localhost environment from the selenium image?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this project](https://github.com/nixel2007/docker-selenium-side-runner), put your .side files in side directory and run `docker-composer up`

Comment: Do you have anyu idea how to make to access your localhost environment from the webdriver image?

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a separate question